# How to monitor microphone input level on MacOS?

Tags: macos, audio-recording, microphone

I am developing an application, which uses microphone. And I want to develop a functionality, allowing users to select microphone and to see input level. Something like you see in MacOS settings. I am able to read data from microphone with no problems, but I don't know how to get input level from this data. I googled a lot and only found some projects for Windows.
[image]

Comment: It looks like you can use `AVAudioRecorder` and its `meteringEnabled`, `updateMeters`, `peakPowerForChannel:`, and `averagePowerForChannel:` methods to accomplish this.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks. It helps a lot. One more question, which method is usually used to detect microphone input level peakPowerForChannel or averagePowerForChannel?

Comment: They both measure it. One returns the peak (maximum) over a period of time, the other returns the average over that period. It depends on what you want to show. Often both are shown.

Comment: It helps. But it's not exactly I want. AVAudioRecorder doesn't allow you to select microphone, it uses the default one.

Comment: Did you finally find a way to SET the microphone level ? I would need this as well

Comment: I didn't have problems with setting a microphone level. If you want to set microphone level try port mixer https://github.com/audacity/audacity/tree/master/lib-src/portmixer
It should use some appropriative native calls